# Is there a hidden limit in SPSocialFeed.Threads?

Tags: 2013, analytics, social-feed

I tried to write a little application to get some kinds of extended Analytics.

I could get some very interesting numbers about Usage, Search terms, Used Memory etc.
But while trying to access all Threads in the Newsfeed of a Teamsite I found a little barrier.
When you try to find out how many posts do exist in one SiteCollection you can do that via:

```
var feedOption = new SPSocialFeedOptions
                        {
                            SortOrder = SPSocialFeedSortOrder.ByCreatedTime,
                            MaxThreadCount = 2000
                        };
var feeds = feedManager.GetFeedFor($"{mySite.Url}/newsfeed.aspx", feedOption);
```

But when you count the number of Threads in the feed:

```
feeds.Threads.Length
```

You will get a maximum of 100 Threads. It seems to be irrelevant what value you set for "MaxThreadCount", you only get Thread 0-99 (also tried using int.MaxValue).

Even if the MicroFeed list in that SiteCollection has 300 Posts, I can`t get the correct number of posts with the feedManager.

I couldn`t find any hint about this limitation in the MSDN description of the [SPSocialFeed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.server.social.spsocialfeed_properties.aspx) class or the [Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/microsoft.office.server.social.spsocialfeed.threads.aspx).

Is there another way to get the number of all existing Threads in a site newsfeed?

Comment: And as mentioned in my Answer below, there is no limit in the description of [SPSocialFeedOptions.MaxThreadCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.server.social.spsocialfeedoptions.maxthreadcount.aspx) in the german version. Only in the US Version of this article you can find the text mentioned by M.Qassas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal behavior, **2000** is invalid value for The `SPSocialFeedOptions.MaxThreadCount`

- The Valid values are between **zero** and **100**.
- The default number of threads returned is **20**.
- Setting the value to zero will set the `MaxThreadCount` property to the default value of **20**.

The `SPSocialFeedOptions.MaxThreadCount` limitations is mentioned at this MSDN documntation [SPSocialFeedOptions.MaxThreadCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.social.spsocialfeedoptions.maxthreadcount.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for that Information. Any Idea how I could achieve my requirement of getting the actual number of posts in a newsfeed ?

Comment: @Leviani You are welcome, unfortunately, no it's a property limitation as mentioned in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I found the reason for my problems.
As M.Qassas wrote, there IS a limit to the int value of the property MaxThreadCount.

I couldn`t find it in the article 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.server.social.spsocialfeedoptions.maxthreadcount.aspx
, even if I set the page language to English.

But if you open the same article with the link from Qassas
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.social.spsocialfeedoptions.maxthreadcount.aspx

You can clearly see another portion of text, telling me
"Gets or sets the maximum number of threads to retrieve. Valid values are between zero and 100"

Really ?

Comment: Great! This is what I have mentioned in my answer since two weeks :) So I am wondering Why my answer is not marked as accepted? :(

Comment: Sorry, my mistake and corrected :)